# Prevent row from expanding table width

Tags: html, css, html-table, width, cell

We have a table with two cells on the first row and one cell in the second one. Each cell width depends on its content.

We want to prevent this second row cell from expanding the table, and make this table width depending on the width of the first row cells, making the second row scrollable.

It is important not to use fixed width or `position: absolute` on this cell, because there has to be another rows below.

Example:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>

        <STYLE>
            .maintable > tbody > tr > td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            .datacell {
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
        </STYLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <TABLE CLASS="maintable">
            <TR>
                <TD>
                    <DIV>
                        <LABEL>Field 1: </LABEL><INPUT TYPE="TEXT"><BR />
                        <LABEL>Field 2: </LABEL><INPUT TYPE="TEXT"><BR />
                        <LABEL>Field 3: </LABEL><INPUT TYPE="TEXT">
                    </DIV>
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <DIV>
                        <LABEL>Field 4: </LABEL><INPUT TYPE="TEXT"><BR />
                        <LABEL>Field 5: </LABEL><INPUT TYPE="TEXT"><BR />
                        <LABEL>Field 6: </LABEL><INPUT TYPE="TEXT">
                    </DIV>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD COLSPAN="2" CLASS="datacell">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TD COLSPAN="2">Test</TD>
        </TABLE>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Can anyone help us?

Comment: Does the second row need to be scrollable?

Comment: Yes! Just adding `overflow:auto` the scroll will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you wanted to achieve but I gave it a shot. Please see [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/pajkvnqj/).

I provided a `max-width` of 1% to the `.datacell` element so that it's width would depend on the other cells.

**CSS**

```
.maintable > tbody > tr > td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.datacell {
    max-width: 1px;
}
```